# Incrementing a pointer inside a fixed block prohibited, it seems it should work

Tags: c#

I get an error trying to increment the pointer.

Cannot assign to ptr because it is a fixed variable CS1656 
Also same error for the other pointer ptruc

```
unsafe void organize_data()
{
    fixed(byte* ptr =  &database[0])
    {
        fixed(byte* ptruc =  &dtbaseuc[0])
        {
            strcnt=1;
            linestrts[0]=0;
            for(int i=0;i<filelen;i++)
            {
                if(*ptr > 96 && *ptr < 123)*ptruc=(byte)((int)*ptr-(int)32);
                    if(*ptr ==13)
                    {
                        linestrts[strcnt]=i+1;
                        strcnt++;
                    }
                ptr++;
                ptruc++;
            }
        }
    }
    textBox2.Text=strcnt.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Seriously, why do you have to use `unsafe` for this?

Comment: &database[0] is address of 0 element of an array, why not try &database instead

Comment: @KamilKrasinski: That wont work. He should use just `database`.

Comment: `database` and `&database[0]` are equivalent in pointer context, and have the type `T*` given `database` is a `T[]`.  `&database` is not valid C# (*"error CS0208: Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type `byte[]'"*).

Comment: I do this in the controversial hope of gaining speed as database is of some size. I may try to code it in the safe way and compare speed if i can find a slow enough computer.

Comment: @KelseyBowman Premature optimization is evil.  Code it the safe way first and then profile.  If this turns out to be the bottleneck, try the unsafe approach.  (And even then, writing a small C library and P/Invoking it might turn out to be even faster.)

Comment: `unsafe` exists for a reason. All the people here saying you shouldnt use it are just people who are bad at performing pointer arithmetic, and probably came from a python or similar background.

Answer (score 9):

Variables declared in a `fixed` block are read-only and cannot be assigned to.  You must instead copy the pointer and then increment the copy.

```
fixed (byte* ptr = &database[0]) {
    byte* dbPtr = ptr;

    ptr++;   // CS1656, ptr is read-only.
    dbPtr++; // Valid.
}
```

Comment: Awesome, as you can see i come from a c background and struggle with c#.  Thanks

Comment: @KelseyBowman No problem.  I would suggest trying to write things the pure C# way and avoid unsafe code.  There is nothing here you can't do with indexed array access.

Comment: @KelseyBowman: cdhowie is right; if you write the code using good practices then the jitter should generate sufficiently fast code. And this is unlikely to be the *slowest* thing in your program.